# How many sockets can one web dyno handle?

Tags: java, php, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to know, how many open sockets can I have per one web dyno?
Suppose that my web application will open a socket to receive 2kb per second ..

Is there a way to calculate this? is it easy to implement? where to start?